# Phonegap developer app javascript Errors

Tags: javascript, cordova, internet-explorer, windows-phone

I trying to run my phonegap app with the "Phongap Developer app" on my windows phone, but it's throwing strange javascript errors, like this:

> Object doesn't supprt property or method "defineProperty"

```
       Object.defineProperty(Detail, "name", {
        get: function () { return this._name; },
        set: function (value) { this._name = value; },
        enumerable: true,
        configurable: true
    });
```

But when I open the html page with the normal Browser from Windowsphone 8.1 everything works perfect.
Has some one an explanation for this problem?

This is the Markup of the index.html:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="Libs/jquery/jquery.js"></script>
        <script src="Libs/angular/angular.js"></script>
        <script src="Libs/angular-ui-router/angular-ui-router.js"></script>
        <script src="Libs/semantic-ui/semantic.js"></script>
        <script src="complete.js"></script>

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="Libs/semantic-ui/semantic.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="Styles/complete.css" />

    </head>
    <body ng-app="app">
        <ui-view></ui-view>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Which document mode is being used when viewing via the container? I suspect it may be putting you into quirks mode, stripping support for things like Object.defineProperty.

Comment: Sorry, but what exactly is the document mode? I'm completly new to phonegap

Comment: Document Modes in Internet Explorer allow the browser (to some degree) to emulate previous versions of Internet Explorer, for the integrity of apps developed in older versions of IE. It may be that PhoneGap is triggering an older document mode, making IE turn off support for `Object.defineProperty`. What value do you get for `document.documentMode`?

Comment: It uses the document mode 5, that explains why nothing is working

Comment: That is *really* bad :) I would check your markup for anything that might be triggering quirks mode (often invalid markup near doctype). Can you share your markup?

Comment: It figured out that I forget the "<!DOCTYPE html>"

Comment: Glad to hear you were able to resolve the issue. I posted this suggestion below in answer-format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like your document is being thrown into an earlier document mode, which strips the browser of modern capabilities like `Object.defineProperty`. You can check the document mode by logging the output of `document.documentMode`.

If you are in a lower document mode, or Quirks Mode, you should consider looking to your markup for any signs of invalid HTML, or a missing doctype. Generally speaking, you should start your document with the following doctype:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

From then on, provided you have valid markup, your document should load in Standards Mode.